# How to specify a ranking for NHibernate search results, based on location of search term in results?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, search, ranking

I have a paged list of search results. A user can search for 'derp' and anything with that sequence of characters anywhere in the name is returned.

I've been asked to change this so that this set of results will initially be ranked by relevance. So if normally the list would be returned as

```
a derp abc // everything is alphabetical
a derp xyz
b derp abc
derp abc
derp def
herp derp a
herp derp b
```

now the list needs to be sorted as

```
derp abc // these guys are given prominence
derp def
a derp abc // the rest of results alphabetical as normal
a derp xyz
b derp abc
herp derp a
herp derp b
```

keeping in mind that this list has to be paged (i.e. I can't just take the search result and manually remove occurrences of 'derp' from the middle and move them to the front), Is there any way with NHibernate that I can specify a required ranking?

Or do I have to do 2 queries, first searching for anything that starts with 'derp' and the second that contains 'derp' but doesn't start with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OrderBy can use Projections, so this will work just fine:

```
var list = session.QueryOver<Store>()
    .Where(s => s.Name.IsLike("My", MatchMode.Anywhere))
    .OrderBy(NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Conditional(
        NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Like(
            NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Property<Store>(s => s.Name), "My",
                MatchMode.Start),
            NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Constant(0),
            NHibernate.Criterion.Projections.Constant(1))).Asc
    .ThenBy(s => s.Name).Asc
    .List();
```

What we are doing here is using a Projection that basically translates to the following SQL:

```
ORDER BY (case when this_.Name like 'My%' then 0 else 1 end)
```